# How to temporarily disable a message listener

Tags: java, jms

What would be a nice and good way to temporarily disable a message listener?  The problem I want to solve is:

- A JMS message is received by a message listener
- I get an error when trying to process the message.
- I wait for my system to get ready again to be able to process the message.
- Until my system is ready, I don't want any more messages, so...
- ...I want to disable the message listener.
- My system is ready for processing again.
- The failed message gets processed, and the JMS message gets acknowledged.
- Enable the message listener again.

Right now, I'm using Sun App Server.  I disabled the message listener by setting it to null in the MessageConsumer, and enabled it again using setMessageListener(myOldMessageListener), but after this I don't get any more messages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about if you don't return from the `onMessage()` listener method until your system is ready to process messages again? That'll prevent JMS from delivering another message on that consumer.

That's the async equivalent of not calling `receive()` in a synchronous case.

There's no multi-threading for a given JMS session, so the pipeline of messages is held up until the `onMessage()` method returns.

I'm not familiar with the implications of dynamically calling `setMessageListener()`.  The javadoc says [there's undefined behavior](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#setMessageListener(javax.jms.MessageListener)) if called "when messages are being consumed by an existing listener or sync consumer".  If you're calling from within `onMessage()`, it sounds like you're hitting that undefined case.

There are [start](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#start())/[stop](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#stop()) methods at the Connection level, if that's not too coarse-grained for you.

Comment: Oh, it really was that simple.  I expected more threads to call the onMessage method.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Connections are thread-safe.  Sessions on down (sessions, consumers, producers) are not thread-safe.  Your code needs to avoid multithreaded access.  To enforce that, JMS couldn't multithread listener calls on one consumer.

Comment: I just noticed that the JMS spec explicitly specifies this serial delivery behavior.  It's section 4.4.16 of the JMS 1.0.2 spec.  In the past I thought it was just implied by the threading rules.

Comment: Can we use Thread.sleep() until the issues gets fixed? Is this the best design?

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved by a workaround replacing the message listener by a receive() loop, but I'm still interested in how to disable a message listener and enable it shortly again.

Comment: Hi, Have you been able to find the solution to pause the receive process of a messagelistener

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me like the messages are being delivered but nothing is happening with them because you have no listener attached.  It's been a while since I've done anything with JMS but don't you want to have the message sent to the dead letter queue or something while you fix the system, and then move the messages back onto the original queue once you're ready for processing again?

Comment: That might be what happens.  Unfortunately, I don't have that control of the jms server, all I can do is to specify a queue to get messages from, no dead letter queue.  I guess I could stop the QueueConnection, but that can't be done from the messagelistener thread.

Comment: How come you don't have access to the JMS server.  As duffymo has rightly pointed out, its the error queue you want access to.  Otherwise you're going to end up replicating behaviour in code that the JMS server provides for you

Comment: I do have that access to the JMS server...in my development environment, but I cannot expect that the users of the application I'm working on (a bridge between two messaging systems) have the same permissions to the JMS server.  Is that dead letter queue the usual way to deal with these problems?

Answer (score 0):

On WebLogic you can set up max retries, an error queue to handle messages that exceed the max retry limit, and other parameters.  I'm not certain off the top of my head, but you also might be able to specify a wait period.  All this is available to you in the admin console.  I'd look at the admin for the JMS provider you've got and see if it can do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss the following code will do the trick:

```
   MBeanServer mbeanServer = MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
    ObjectName objName = new ObjectName("jboss.j2ee:ear=MessageGateway.ear,jar=MessageGateway-EJB.jar,name=MessageSenderMDB,service=EJB3");
    JMSContainerInvokerMBean invoker = (JMSContainerInvokerMBean) MBeanProxy.get(JMSContainerInvokerMBean.class, objName, mbeanServer);

    invoker.stop(); //Stop MDB
    invoker.start(); //Start MDB
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call

```
messageConsumer.setMessageListener(null);
```

inside your MessageListener implementation and schedule the reestablishment task (for example in ScheduledExecutorService). This task should call

```
connection.stop();
messageConsumer.setMessageListener(YOUR_NEW_LISTENER);
connection.start();
```

and it will be working. start() and stop() methods are used for restarting delivery structrues (not TCP connection).

Read the Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#stop--

> Temporarily stops a connection's delivery of incoming messages. Delivery can be restarted using the connection's start method. When the connection is stopped, delivery to all the connection's message consumers is inhibited: synchronous receives block, and messages are not delivered to message listeners.

Answer (score 0):

For temporarily stops a connection's delivery of incoming messages you need to use `stop()` method from `Connection` interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#stop--

Just don't call `connection.stop()` from `MessageListener` because according to JMS spec. you will get deadlock or exception. Instead you can call `connection.stop()` from different thread, you just need to synchronize `MessageListener` and thread that going to suspend connection with function `connection.stop()`