# Is that possible to stop programmatically my MDB (Message Driven Bean) listening a IBM mq in jboss server?

Tags: java, jms, jboss7.x, ibm-mq

I'm struggling to program a controller that I can switch MDB on or off. I was trying to use JNDI lookup to find the MDB instance in my Jboss server, then make it controlled. Is this possible?

Comment: Give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625725/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-message-listener

Answer (score 1):

Yes, via JMX. You can find JMX beans for JMS Activation (MDB) under "WebSphere:type=J2CMessageEndpoint,*"
Then can can "invoke" methods "pause" or "resume" on the MBean of the Activation

Comment: Hi, Thank you for response.  I actually tried this method. But i was confused with the J2CMessageEndpoint.  Is this Endpoint in Queue Server or the server my MDB runs on?

Comment: The MBean represent the "JMS Activation specifications" you defined at the WAS console, that is referenced by your MDB in your application